# How to copy a character from basic string into a vector string?

Tags: string, c++11, vector

[image] //Defining the class

```
class Hangman
{
    private:
        vector<string> dictionary;          //stores all the words
        vector<string> secretWord;          //stores the secret word
        vector<string> misses;              //keeps record of wrong guesses
        vector<string> displayVector;           //Stores "_"
        string originalWord;                //stores a copy of secret word to display at the 
end of game.
        bool gameOver = false;                      //Flag to check if the player lost or 
still in the game.
        int totalAttempts;
            
    public:                                 
    void selectRandWord();                      
};
```

//This is the function i am having problem in.

```
void Hangman::selectRandWord()
{
    secretWord.clear();
```

//word is a basic string that stores a random word. lets say "Hello World".

```
    string word;
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int random = (rand() % dictionary.size()) + 1;
```

//I store a random word from vector to word.

```
    word = dictionary[random];
    transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);           
    originalWord = word;
    for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) 
    {
```

//This line has the error: [Error] invalid user-defined conversion from 'char' to 'std::vectorstd::basic_string<char >::value_type&& {aka std::basic_string&&}' [-fpermissive]

//What I am trying to do is take each character from word(for example: "H") and push it back into the vector string secretWord.

```
        secretWord.push_back(word[index]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why is `secretWord` a `vector<string>` in the first place? Shouldn't it be a `string`?

Comment: I did not post my full program here but basically, I wanted to be able to use the vector library functions like pop, pushback, erase, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `secretWord` is now a `vector<string>` type, so it's a collection of possibly many words, I'm not sure if that's what you really intend to have judging by the name. If it indeed is ok and you want to store every single character from `word` as a separate `string` in `secretWord`, then you need to replace `push_back` call with `emplace_back` call as the other method actually does two things at a time: constructs a `string` from the `char` you pass to it and appends the `string` to the end of the container, like this

```
secretWord.emplace_back(1, word[index]);
```

Mere `push_back` fails because it needs to be provided with an object of the type your `vector` stores, so you could also solve your problem by explicitly constructing a `string` from your `char`:

```
secretWord.push_back(string(1, word[index]));
```

I suggest you give a read to these: [emplace back reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) and [push back reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) if you're interested in copy/move details.

Comment: when I use emplace_back and try to compile the program, it opens up some file named "allocator.h". In this file it gives errors. Basically it says: [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]. In the file allocator.h the code that shows up with this error is: { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

Comment: I added the screen shot of my program that shows the error.

Comment: @muhammadmuzaib My bad, I actually didn't know that you cannot construct a `string` from a single `char` in C++ without specyfing the number of times you want that `char` to be repeated (copied) in the `string` (see [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) under #2). So do it accordingly like this: ```secretWord.emplace_back(1, word[index]);``` Again, C++ reference can be of great help to you in such doubts, for instance you can find out that another solution would be to cast this `char` to a pointer to a `char` (to match `basic_string` constructor version #5)

Comment: @muhammadmuzaib As for the `char*` version, remember that strings seen as contiguous bytes pointed to by `char*` need to be null terminated, so the other version of constructing might be tricky and require explicit null termination. However, there are plenty of other options of converting a `char` to a `string` listed [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-char-to-string-cpp/).